# VB script BOM UTF-8 Encoded File Remove BOM

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 to get back an xml document from a url. It has a "ï»¿" at the start of the file causing XMLDOM.loadxml to fail.

Is there a way to

1. Remove the BOM from the string when reading from URL
2. Have the xml parser ignore the BOM

(NOTE: I can't change the response from the URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You can clear the BOM at the beginning of the resulting string. I wrote for you this function. Pass a url as a argument and the function will return clean from BOM response.
Stackoverflow have some problems when user try to post VBScript code. You can see function here:
http://pastebin.com/mQysnW40